# Design Changes When Changing Devices That Have the Same Screen Size

Tags: java, android, android-layout

So my android app looks the way it's supposed to look on the Nexus 5, but when I change the device to a Pixel, the design changes and it's not the design I want. Both devices have the same screen size (1080x1920).

Here's a link to what the screens look like:

[image: screen]

Can anyone tell me why the design looks different even though the screen sizes are the same? I have created all the necessary drawable folders so I don't understand what's going on.

Answer (score 2):

They have the same widht and height in pixels (1080x1920) but they are different in terms of dpi:

- Nexus 5 - 360dp x 640dp
- Pixel - 411dp x 731dp

Source: https://material.io/tools/devices/

So if you set your 3 buttons to be 120dp width they will not fill entire screen. Your UI should be more flexible. To achieve desirable look you can use chains with ConstraintLayout or layout_weight with LinearLayout.

Comment: So what do I do because I already have a drawable-xxhdpi folder that has the images, which is why it works fine with the Nexus 5 and not the Pixel?

Comment: You can try scaling your drawables. https://robots.thoughtbot.com/android-imageview-scaletype-a-visual-guide

Comment: How would I scale the images for only one device so that it doesn't affect another screen?